# How can i remove an element in a string list in java?

Tags: java, list

As u can see i wanna delete or remove the ingrediant which equals my ingredientid from my SplitedIgrediants list, i've tried with remove or delete but it's appear an error. So how can i do to delete this ingredient elemant please from my list in JAVA.

```
        String ingredientid = request.getParameter("id");
        DbHandler dbsplt = new DbHandler();
        for (String ingrediant : SplitedIngrediants) {
            if (ingrediant.equals(ingredientid)) {
                //HERE REMOVE THE ingredient from SplitedIngrediants list
            }
```

Comment: how are we to know? we don't even know the type of SplitedIngrediants

Comment: What is `SplitedIngrediants`. Best we see the other parts of the code

Comment: also: why do you tag jquery for a java question?

Comment: @Stultuske look at the code closely, it's a for each loop, so since it's wrote in the title and the sub element is of type String, i guess SplitedIngrediants is a List of type String aswell.

Comment: @xoxel you have no idea how many people think String[] myList is a 'list of Strings'

Comment: @Stultuske you got a point sir

Comment: @Stultuske it's a string list  String[] SplitedIngrediants

Comment: @Stultuske i tage jee don't know why it's became jquery

Comment: "string list String[]" @Stultuske you got all my excuses.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove elements from a Collection while iterating on it (you will get some `ConcurrentModificationException`) except if you manually declare the `iterator` and use `iterator.remove()`.

Example :

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

list.add(3);
list.add(4);
list.add(5);

Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator();
Integer current;
while (it.hasNext()) {
    current = it.next();
    if(current.equals(4)) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Ouput :

```
[3, 5]
```

The reason behind that is that the "foreach" construction internally creates an iterator. The aim of the iterator is to ensure that each element of the iterable is visited exactly once. So if you add/remove elements from the iterable without using the iterator methods, the iterator can no longer fulfil its task.

2nd option : while iterating on the list, make a list of the items to delete and delete them after iterating.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String ingredientid = request.getParameter("id");
SplitedIngrediants.removeAll(Collections.singleton(ingredientid));
```

Example code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        l.add("first");
        l.add("first");
        l.add("second");

        String ingredientid = "first";

        l.removeAll(Collections.singleton(ingredientid));

        System.out.println(l);
    }
```

With SplitedIngrediants is a String array try this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String[] SplitedIngrediants = new String[] { "first", "first", "second" };

    String ingredientid = "first";

    List<String> NewSplitedIngrediants = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String ingrediant : SplitedIngrediants) {
        if (!ingrediant.equals(ingredientid)) {
            NewSplitedIngrediants.add(ingrediant);
        }
    }
    SplitedIngrediants = new String[NewSplitedIngrediants.size()];
    SplitedIngrediants = NewSplitedIngrediants.toArray(SplitedIngrediants);
    for (String ingrediant : SplitedIngrediants) {
        System.out.println(ingrediant);
    }

}
```

Comment: What Collections for and singleton for ?

Comment: It's said that cannot find symobol of removeAll

Comment: SplitedIngrediants is a java.util.List? If yes then there must be removeAll() method.

Comment: No i declare like this String[] SplitedIngrediants a table of strings

Comment: Because what i do actually is that i split a string with "," and add it to my string table

Comment: Ur method seems to work but now i have a problem when i try to split my string and affect it to that list

Comment: For String[] I have added some sample code that should work.